# Migration from DC in Windows Server 2008 R2 to Windows Server 2016

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, domain-controller, migration, windows-server-2016

We are having a project to migrate a Windows 2008 R2 domain controller to Windows Server 2016, and I have some doubts:
1) While I am configuring and migrating user accounts to the new DC, can I keep both DCs alive on the network (W2008 and W2016)?
2) Is there any way to migrate the user accounts from one DC to the other? MS tool?
3) When I will put a computer (Windows 7 Pro and Windows 10 Pro) in the new domain (we will change the current domain name), the user's local profile (we do not have a network profile), such as programs, icons, settings, etc will be maintain? Or a new local profile will be created, since the domain name is another?

Comment: So you're migrating to a new domain, not just introducing a new Domain Controller in the existing domain. Is that correct?

Comment: Migrating from old one (Windows 2008) to new one (Windows 2016). And we will change the domain name.

Comment: I thought about the next one. As I have to do two processes, user migration and name switching, I thought of the following strategy:

1) create an AD / DC with W2016 with the new domain name I need;
2) create a relationship of trust between the domains (old and new);
3) gradually migrate users, profiles, permissions, etc;
4) undo the relationship of trust between domains;
5) remove the old domain and the AD / DC W2008R2;

      Does it work?